# Changing theorem numbering from chapter.section.number to chapter.number later in document

Tags: amsthm, newtheorem

For most of my document (using document class "report" and using the amsthm package), I am happy with the theorem numbering that `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]` produces, i.e.

> Theorem 1.2.3.

is the 3rd theorem in section 2 of chapter 1. However, a later chapter has no sections, and so my theorem numbering looks like

> Theorem 6.0.1

The 0 bothers me :). How do I change the \newtheorem command to number according to chapter, without changing the numbering earlier in the document?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `\counterwithin` macro.

```
% theoremprob.tex  SE 633030

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

%\usepackage{chngcntr} %%%% now in basic LaTeX 

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
%%% default theorem number (based on current section)
\section{A section}
\begin{thm}
  maths
\end{thm}

\chapter{Second}
\counterwithin{thm}{chapter} % make theorem number based on current chapter
\begin{thm}
  maths
\end{thm}

\chapter{Third}
\counterwithin{thm}{section} % make theorem number based on current section
\section{A section}
\begin{thm}
  maths
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

the `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` macros were originally defined by the `chngcntr` package but are now part of basic LaTeX. You can read the manual for these macros by `texdoc chngcntr`